# Building propensity score for a cluster

Tags: classification, cluster-analysis

I am working on an exercise to build influencer score for each user in my data set. What that means is that a user with higher engagement should get higher score and vice versa. however, i have many different type of engagement variables and i am not sure which one should weight higher.

so, i first did a cluster analysis to divide users into different group based on engagement activity using 5 different types of engagement. Based on this, i found that one of the cluster has high level of engagement across all the different types of engagement variables. This is the group i am interested in. however, it is possible that the group size i get may be smaller than the number of users i want to use in future. so, i want to now use these clusters and create a propensity score.

e.g. in the cluster analysis, say i get 5 clusters c1, c2,c3,c4,c5 and c5 is my cluster of interest. so, i give all users in c5 a value of 1 (= influencer) and i give all users in c1 to c4 a value of 0 (= not influencer). now, i use this binary variable and build a logistic regression model (using same engagement variables as used for clustering) to get propensity for everyone to an influencer. this way, i can change the threshold to reduce or increase the numbers of users i want to select.

Now, the issue i am running in is that one of the engagement variable is able to predict influencer very well and hence my propensity scores are very close to either 1 or 0 which defeats the purpose of why i wanted the propensity score in the first place.

S0, 2 questions - 
1) is this approach of building a unsupervised classification and then using this to build supervised classification a sound approach of what i am trying to do?
2) how do i reduce the contribution from the variable that predicts influencer really well to ensure that i get much more smoother curve instead of values near 0 or 1. i don't want to remove this variable from the model as this is important from business perspective.

Comment: Since you are interested in the users that have high values in each score, why can't you just take the weighted average score, rather than overengineering?

Comment: That is one approach, but i am not sure what weights to use.